# How can I view Indices in Apache Directory Studio?

Tags: apache, ldap

A different team has set up the LDAP configuration. I was wondering If there is a way to view indices for attributes that may or may not have been set up. Is there a way to do this in Apache Directory Studio? I want to know if there is an index for a certain 'id' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which LDAP server you are connecting to and how the it's stored.

E.g. in NetIQ eDirectory you would look up the server object using the LDAP filter:

```
(objectClass=ncpServer)
```

Then you would look at the `indexDefinition`attribute to see every index definition for a particular server.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid, you can query/update etc. indices only with administration commands, like

```
dsconf list-indexes
```

, etc. (s. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19424-01/820-4809/gadsn/index.html)
i.e. you should have got admin/manager rights (password).

Whether from ApacheStudio:

Have you got / configured cn=manager,... access config in your Apache Studio?
If so, you can try explore tree cn=config.